# Matrix representation after change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations, change-of-basis, wolfram-alpha

I am trying to solve this task using Wolfram Notebook. I would like to know how new matrix is calculated (part b) after a change of basis.

[image]

**Part a**: I decided to show this part because **part b** is a continuation of **part a**

Basis for y=-x:

```
p := {{ 0, -1 },{-1, 0}}
```

[image]

30 degrees rotation:

```
RotationTransform[30*Degree, {0, 0}][{x, y}]
```

[image]

q is 30 degrees rotation as matrix:

```
q:={{Sqrt[3]/2, -2^(-1)}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}}
```

[image]

```
a:=p.q
```

[image]

**Part b**

New basis:

```
w:={{1,-1},{-1,2}}
```

[image]

I did not understand how exactly change of basis works, however, I tried to implement what I learned in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2LTAUO1TdA):

```
Inverse[w].p.w.a
```

[image]

This way seems to me not correct.

Question: How can I calculate new matrix representation after a change of basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New matrix representation after a change of basis:

```
Inverse[w].a.w
```

[image]